# How to Unbind the Script on specific page

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, copy-paste

I Guys i have a web application in MVC where we had not enabled Right click due to security reason and i want to Enable that Right click on singe page Below is the code

JavaScript for no rightclick & copy Named : ContentCopy.js

```
function mischandler()

    { return !1 }
    function mousehandler(n) {


        var e = isns ? n : event, t = isns ? e.which : e.button; return 2 == t || 3 == t ? !1 : void 0
    } var isctrl = !1; document.onkeyup = function (n) { return 17 == n.which ? (isctrl = !1, !1) : void 0 },
    document.onkeydown = function (n)
    { return 17 == n.which ? (isctrl = !0, !1) : 67 == n.which && 1 == isctrl ? !1 : void 0 },
    document.onkeypress = function (n) { return 17 == n.which ? (isctrl = !0, !1) : 67 == n.which && 1 == isctrl ? !1 : void 0 };
    var isns = "netscape" == navigator.appname ? 1 : 0;
    "netscape" == navigator.appname && document.captureevents(event.mousedown || event.mouseup),
    document.oncontextmenu = mischandler, document.onmousedown = mousehandler, document.onmouseup = mousehandler;
```

I had Called this JS in Layout.

What i had tried :
    $(document).ready(function () {

```
    $(document).undelegate("~/Content/js/ContentCopy.js");
    $(document).undelegate("mischandler");
    $('#BoxId').unbind("mischandler");
    $(document).removeEventListener("mischandler", mischandler);
});
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: You have to bind the event handler and then unbind it, using jquery `on()` and `off()` methods http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: Can you pl help me out with the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't get the complete logic what you've written. Just try overwriting the method mischandler to

```
function mischandler() { return 1 }
```

and check the functionality.
https://jsfiddle.net/towkwa6q/